# Eastern Mediterranean Bronze Age Sprachbund

Tags: greek, hebrew, ancient, armenian, sprachbund

I would like to know whether there is any research on the interactions between Bronze Age languages of the Near and Middle East like Greek, Hebrew, Aramaic, Phoenician, Persian and Hittite, in a way of making a sort of ancient Sprachbund.

I am especially interested in the subject when it comes to nominal composition. For example, how Θεόδωρος might be a calque from the Hebrew Nathaniel. But I welcome any research in morphosyntax in general. Research on borrowing of vocabulary is also welcome, but I pass research on toponyms.

Comment: There is, but maybe there should be more.  One way to start is to look at terms derived  from ancient languages in the modern indigenous languages of the region like Greek, Armenian, Persian and Aramaic.  For example https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Terms_derived_from_Akkadian

Comment: there's plenty of research into early borrowings and Wanderworter, but I'm not aware of research suggesting a Sprachbund

Comment: I don't understand why this question is valid. Isn't an OP supposed to try and do his/her own research before asking a question?

Comment: @Lambie I think you are supposed to go back to Reddit.

Comment: I don't understand that either.

Comment: I do find plenty about the Anatolian influence on early Greek.